# How to manipulate the file pointer in Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, file-pointer

So I am reading through a calendar file to insert a date into the file and I want the dates to remain in chronoligical order. The problem comes when I find the place where the date should go, the file is already looking past the point I want to insert into.

The calendar file I'm looking at looks like this:

```
# November 2010
11/26/2010
11/27/2010
11/28/2010
11/29/2010
11/30/2010
# December
12/24/2010
12/25/2010
12/26/2010
12/27/2010
12/28/2010
12/29/2010
12/30/2010
```

and my code looks like this:

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    if (substr($line, 0, 1) =~ m/\#/ || $line =~ m/calendar/) { #if the line is commented out or contains the calendar's name skip to next line
        next;
    }
    chomp($line);
    my ($temp_month, $temp_day, $temp_year) = split(/\//, $line, 3);
    if ($year == $temp_year && $month == $temp_month && $day < $temp_day) {
        ?
    }
}
```

So are there any suggestions as to how to point to the previous spot in the file?

Comment: Why not just print the dates to a new file? Then you can put the print statements in the correct order easily enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you need to move randomly around a file is [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html). But there's more information on how to approach this problem in the Perl FAQ - [How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a great use for the [Tie::File](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aFile) module.  You can treat the file like an array and not have to worry about the current position of the file pointer. It also does not depend on loading the entire file into memory - so it will work with massive files.

```
use Tie::File;

tie @array, 'Tie::File', $file;

for (my $i =0; $i <= @array; $i++) {
    if (/date comparison/*see note below) {
        splice @array, $i, 0, $new_date;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to use perl's array functions, like splice, to insert new lines.

But, you also have a big problem with your date comparison strategy.  What if there are no dates in the file yet for a given month, year combination?  You will loop through and not find a spot for it. Check out [timelocal](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aLocal), which you can use to convert both the dates into epoch time and then compare them.

```
use Time::Local;
my $temp_epoch = timelocal(0,0,0,$temp_day,$temp_month -1, $temp_year-1900);
if ($epoch < $temp_epoch ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) and [tell](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html) will solve the problem of winding back. You will end up overwriting currently existing lines. The lazy solution is to use [Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile), another possibility it so read a file while writing out the new version, and then replacing the old version with the new one when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The standard perl solution is to throw memory at the problem:

```
open( my $FILE, ....);   #open in read/write mode
my @lines = <FILE>;      #slurp in all lines of file
... insert (or delete?) into array ...
truncate( $FILE, 0 );    #if deleting, you will need to truncate
seek( $FILE, 0, 0 );
print $FILE @lines;
```

To be more efficient you could just write from the point of change rather than everything, but if speed is not important, simplicity has less bug potential.

Comment: if there are any concurrency concerns it would be better to write a new file and then rename it to the original file name

Comment: Locking may be better than renaming in case of concurrency concerns. However locking and renaming would be safer in all cases.